# How to divide with PHP.

Tags: php

I'm trying to divide in PHP, but I don't get the correct answer when I echo it out.

```
<?php
$names = file('rating.txt');

// To check the number of lines 
echo "In the textfile: " . count($names).'<br>';

$sum = 0;

foreach($names as $name)
{
$sum = $sum + $name;
}

echo "Total sum: " . $sum;

?>
```

I tried:

```
($sum/$name)
```

But that gives me the wrong result. If I try:

```
($sum/$names)
```

I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\xampp\htdocs\lab5\rating\index.php on line 55

How do I get the `$sum` divided by the number of lines I have in the text file?

Comment: If you want to divide, you need a **number** to divide by.  You don't have one right now.  You need to change your code to have a second number.

Comment: This code `$sum = $sum + $name;` must be replaced by `$sum .= $name;`

Comment: @Foo_Chow The [file](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) method does return an array ([line_number]=>[content]).

Answer (score 1):

Change `$sum = $sum + $name;` to `$sum .= intval($name);`. `intval` converts the string into a number.

If this does not work, the problem is with `rating.txt`, which you are not showing. `($sum/$names)` won't work because you can only divide a number by a another number (Which should be non-zero).